# Maximum subarray sum : why my code is so time consuming?

Tags: python

My code is working for small lists but for large ones is so time consuming and even not working(ex: lists with more than 100 numbers). Is any problem with my code or it works?

```
def max_sequence(arr):
    length = len(arr)
    if length == 0:
        return 0
    if all(i < 0 for i in arr) == True:
        return 0
    max_num = 0
    sum_num = 0
    for i in range(length):
        sum_num = 0
        for j in range(i,length):
            sum_num += arr[j]
            if sum_num > max_num:
                max_num = sum_num
    return max_num
```

Comment: The time complexity of your code grows quadratically in the length of your input. Meaning that when your input is 10x longer, the runtime is ~100x longer. What are you trying to compute? Are you allowed to use numpy? If so it looks like you could speed things up tremendously.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is correct. However, your complexity is `O(N^2)`. There is an `O(N)` solution, look up "Kadane's algorithm".

[What is complexity](https://www.lancaster.ac.uk/stor-i-student-sites/lidia-andre/2021/04/27/time-complexity-whats-that/)

[Maximum subarray problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem)

Answer (score 2):

In this code sample, you are iterating over the list twice. The computational complexity of the algorithm is O(n^2).
You can use a different algorithm with O(n) complexity. See details in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem, specifically "Kadane's algorithm".